# Why is the variable not being defined with the extended class calling the main class function on my computer?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a strange problem, the following code outputs correctly on websites testing code like CodeSandbox, TypeScript Sandbox. But on my computer (and even a virtual machine that I created) the result is different

```
class Test2 {
  constructor() {
    this.initView();
  }

  protected initView() {
    console.log("Test2 initView");
  }
}

class Test extends Test2 {
  private _test: number;

  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(this._test); // undefined
  }

  protected initView() {
    console.log('initView Test')
    this._test = 123;
  }
}

new Test();
```

Expected output:

```
initView Test
123
```

Current output using the same code as [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript):

```
initView Test
undefined
```

[Showing the output on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1ib3.png)

Can someone give me a light, I do not know what happens I am days trying to solve this

Comment: Can you add your tsconfig.json file, typescript version for both environments, your local machine and other places where you tried it?

Comment: But know that what you're doing here is not safe at all. You should have got a compilation error if you use strict mode, like-  "_test has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor".

Comment: @Mateen yes I know it is not safe I disabled strict for this. I will add the information